# How to have JavaScript generate n number of var buttons for modals

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

Please forgive me if I misuse some terms here; JavaScript is outside of my regular work domain.

I have a Flask app where the route generates the proper database query, passing *n* number of entries to the page. In Jinja code, I have turned the device.DTxProgramName field for each entry into a button, which opens up a Modal box. However, the issue that I'm running into is that only the first instance of the device.DTxProgramName button opens up a modal box. All of the other buttons do nothing.

During some testing, where I explicitly defined two buttons and explicitly defined two var btn and var modal, I was able to get the effect that I was looking for. However, this requires hard coding this information, which is not the route I can take.

Can someone with more experience in JavaScript suggest what steps I can take to create the vars I need for each device.DTxProgramName button to function properly?

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{% block content %}
    {% for device in devices %}
        <article class="media device">
            <div class="media-body">
              <button id="DeviceButton" class="btn">{{ device.DTxProgramName }}</button>
              <div id="DeviceModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <p>{{device.DTxProgramName}}</p>
                  <span class="close"></span>
                </div>            
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("DeviceModal");
        
        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("DeviceButton");
        
        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        
        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
        
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a referencing method to make the active modal selection dynamic. What's happening here is the JS assigns a function on all the `button` clicks and individually selects the modal based on `data-modal` value. All you have to ensure is `data-modal` is same as the `id` of child modal element and they are unique for each device.

Also changed your hiding modal function. Using `==` will trigger the closing only if the click in on modal. Changed it to `!==`.

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{% block content %}
{% for device in devices %}
    <article class="media device">
        <div class="media-body">
          <button data-modal="deviceModal1" class="deviceModals btn">{{ device.DTxProgramName }}</button>
          <div id="deviceModal1" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <p>{{device.DTxProgramName}}</p>
              <span class="close"></span>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
<script>
  // Get the buttons that open the modal ...
  var btns = document.getElementByClassName("deviceModals"),
      activeModal;
    
  // ... and assign each button a function when the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  for (let i = 0;i<btns.length;i++){
    let btn = btns[i];
    btn.onclick = function() {
      // Get the modal
      let activeModal= document.getElementById(btn.dataset.modal);
      activeModal.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
    
  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target !== activeModal) {
      activeModal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```